# How to play mp3 files using html5 in flask

Tags: python-3.x, html, flask, web-applications

Experts,

I am trying to play mp3 files, upon click, in my web browser(Firefox). I am having trouble doing so. Here is the scenario, I am running flask server and my html is,

```
<div class="songlist" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:600px;">                                          
¦ ¦ <p>                                                                                                     
¦ ¦ ¦ {% for songname, song in songs.items() %}                                                             
¦ ¦ ¦ <ul>                                                                                                  
¦ ¦ ¦ ¦ <audio class="songthumb" control="controls">                                                     
¦ ¦ ¦ ¦ ¦ <source src="{{ 'file://'}}{{ song }}" type="audio/mpeg"/>                                        
¦ ¦ ¦ ¦ </audio>                                                                                          
¦ ¦ ¦ ¦ <a href="{{ 'file://'}}{{ song }}">{{ songname }}</a>                
¦ ¦ ¦ </ul>                                                                                                 
¦ ¦ ¦ {% endfor %}                                                                                          
¦ ¦ </p>                                                                                                    
</div>
```

When I load the page, I get the HTML5 audio controls for a moment and it disappears. 
If I click the link, nothing happens.

I tried to verify this is not a html5, firefox and flask issue by issuing the following from the terminal `firefox mysong.mp3`. The audio plays through the firefox with the controls on.

I am new to webapp development and this is a learning stuff for me.

My mp3 files are in a filesystem directory. I query the path to the song from a db (sqlite3) using sqlalchemy. If my view matters, here it goes,

```
@app.route('/main/', defaults={'page':1}, methods=['GET', 'POST'])             
@app.route('/main/<int:page>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])                        
def page(page):                                                                                               

#------------------ Create a session and establish DB connection-------    
    Ses = sessionmaker(bind=song_cur)                                                                         
    S= Ses()                                                                                                  
    per_page = 50                                                                                             
    base_query = S.query(songdbdef.Songs.songname,                             
    ¦   ¦   songdbdef.Songs.location)                                                                         
    total = base_query.count()                                                                                
    pages = list()                                                                                            
    # Generate pages list                                                                                     
    for  i in range(int(math.ceil(total/per_page))):                           
    ¦   pages.append(i)                                                                                       
    q = base_query.limit(per_page).offset(page*per_page).all()                 
    # Converting to dicitonary for iteration                                                                  
    q = dict(q)                                                                                               

    if q:                                                                                                     
    ¦   return render_template('main_songs.html', songs = q, pages=pages)      
    else:                                                                                                     
    ¦   return "No song in the list"
```

What I anticipated is, I would get audio controls against each song and I should be able to play them using the controls. I understand I am doing something wrong.

Could someone point me to the right direction/shed some light on how to troubleshoot and fix the issue to get what I wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Firefox, blocks the `file:\\` protocol. I am now serving the `mp3` files through `http` using `ComplexHTTPServer`. Starting the service from the directory containing mp3 files. To do so, added the following in the runscript

```
suprocess.Popen(['python', '-m', 'ComplexHTTPServer', '<port_number>'], cwd=<mp3_directory>)
```

Hope this helps some beginner like me.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox is likely blocking access to your audio files because it appears you are loading them from the main file system via the `file://` URI scheme, a security risk in browsers.

Files can be accessed like this from a plain html page if that page is also opened in the browser with the file URI scheme (i.e `file:///my-audio-page.html`), but because Flask runs as an application *serving* files, this functionality will be blocked.

You should instead look for a way to move your files into a `static/` directory *within* your Flask application so that they can be served from it:

```
FlaskApp/
  app.py
  templates/
    my-audio-page.html
  static/
    song1.mp3
    song2.mp3
```

and then in your template:

```
{% for songname, song in songs.items() %}
<audio controls>
    <source src="{{ url_for('static', filename=song) }}" type="file/mpeg">
</audio>
{% endfor %}
```

See the documentation for static files: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#static-files

Comment: Hi @user2921551. Thanks on the first hand. I, indeed, tried what you have suggested. But no difference, the controls appears for bit longer but disappears eventually. After surfing around, it looks like a good idea might be is to serve `mp3` via http. I am also exploring other alternatives like using `uWSGI+nginx`, although they're for production, to see it is possible.