# Can't play audio on Python Flask server, but works fine on local

Tags: javascript, python, html, button, server

I have written a Python Flask program, MusicServer.py, that creates a server on my local network and have connected the render_template() to my HTML page.html file. When I run the server, everything loads as intended, but the buttons to play the music no longer work, even though they work as intended when I press the buttons to play the music when I run the standalone page.html file.

I have already tried attempting to play the audio files by running them to play through the actual python server file, I tried an HTML form, I tried Javascript, which also works as intended on the raw HTML execution but not the server, and I have tried using the built in HTML audio tag.

***python MusicServer.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import os
import socket

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('page.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
    app.run(debug = True, host = "0.0.0.0", port = 80)
    os.system("python run MusicServer.py")
```

---

***HTML page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>
        Music Server Test
    </title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="pink">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var songs = [new Audio('SwedenC418.mp3'), 
        new Audio('FirefliesOwlCity.mp3')];

        var counter = 1;

        function playSong(song)
        {
        if (counter % 2 == 1)
        {
        song.play();
        }
        else
        {
        song.pause();
        }
        counter = counter + 1;
        }
    </script>

<h1>
    <center>
        Welcome to the Music Box!
    </center>
</h1>

<button onclick="playSong(songs[0]);" name="SweedenC418">
    Sweden- C418 (Caution and Crisis Remix)
</button>

<button onclick="playSong(songs[1]);" name="FirefliesOwlCity">
    Fireflies- Owl City
</button>

<audio controls>
    <source src="SwedenC418.mp3">
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

The expected result is to be able to play audio via button press on an HTML page hosted by Python Flask, but the actual result is only displaying the page with no button functionality.

The two error messages I get in the python console when I try to execute the Fireflies song via HTML button when I try to do it running on the server is 
"GET /FirefliesOwlCity.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
and for the Sweden C418 song the error is 
"GET /SwedenC418.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: How are you serving those MP3 files?

Comment: Does the browser console say any errors? Not the python console.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51924238/how-to-play-mp3-files-using-html5-in-flask/51960006 Check this link out man